# changing functionality of an enum

Tags: swift, swift3, enums

I'm using Vapor but this a pure Swift question. Vapor has an enum "Status" defined as : (I removed some cases in the enum here as this code is already quite long)

```
public enum Status {
    case `continue`
    case switchingProtocols
    case processing

    case ok
    case created
    case accepted
    case nonAuthoritativeInformation
    case noContent
    case resetContent
    case partialContent

    case multipleChoices
    case movedPermanently
    case found
    case seeOther
    case notModified
    case useProxy
    case switchProxy
    case temporaryRedirect
    case permanentRedirect

    case badRequest
    case unauthorized
    case paymentRequired
    case forbidden
    case notFound
    case methodNotAllowed
    case notAcceptable
    //removed a bunch of other 'cases' for the sake of brevity

    case other(statusCode: Int, reasonPhrase: String)
}

extension Status {
    public init?(officialCode: Int) {
        switch officialCode {
        case Status.`continue`.statusCode:                    self = .`continue`
        case Status.switchingProtocols.statusCode:            self = .switchingProtocols
        case Status.processing.statusCode:                    self = .processing

        case Status.ok.statusCode:                            self = .ok
        case Status.created.statusCode:                       self = .created
        case Status.accepted.statusCode:                      self = .accepted
        case Status.nonAuthoritativeInformation.statusCode:   self = .nonAuthoritativeInformation
        case Status.noContent.statusCode:                     self = .noContent
        case Status.resetContent.statusCode:                  self = .resetContent
        case Status.partialContent.statusCode:                self = .partialContent

        case Status.multipleChoices.statusCode:               self = .multipleChoices
        case Status.movedPermanently.statusCode:              self = .movedPermanently
        case Status.found.statusCode:                         self = .found
        case Status.seeOther.statusCode:                      self = .seeOther
        case Status.notModified.statusCode:                   self = .notModified
        case Status.useProxy.statusCode:                      self = .useProxy
        case Status.switchProxy.statusCode:                   self = .switchProxy
        case Status.temporaryRedirect.statusCode:             self = .temporaryRedirect
        case Status.permanentRedirect.statusCode:             self = .permanentRedirect

        case Status.badRequest.statusCode:                    self = .badRequest
        case Status.unauthorized.statusCode:                  self = .unauthorized
        case Status.paymentRequired.statusCode:               self = .paymentRequired
        case Status.forbidden.statusCode:                     self = .forbidden
        case Status.notFound.statusCode:                      self = .notFound
        case Status.methodNotAllowed.statusCode:              self = .methodNotAllowed
        case Status.notAcceptable.statusCode:                 self = .notAcceptable

        default: return nil
        }
    }

    public init(statusCode: Int, reasonPhrase: String? = nil) {
        if let official = Status(officialCode: statusCode) {
            self = official
        } else {
            self = .other(statusCode: statusCode, reasonPhrase: reasonPhrase ?? "")
        }
    }
}

extension Status {
    public var statusCode: Int {
        switch self {
        case .`continue`:                    return 100
        case .switchingProtocols:            return 101
        case .processing:                    return 102

        case .ok:                            return 200
        case .created:                       return 201
        case .accepted:                      return 202
        case .nonAuthoritativeInformation:   return 203
        case .noContent:                     return 204
        case .resetContent:                  return 205
        case .partialContent:                return 206

        case .multipleChoices:               return 300
        case .movedPermanently:              return 301
        case .found:                         return 302
        case .seeOther:                      return 303
        case .notModified:                   return 304
        case .useProxy:                      return 305
        case .switchProxy:                   return 306
        case .temporaryRedirect:             return 307
        case .permanentRedirect:             return 308


        case .badRequest:                    return 400
        case .unauthorized:                  return 401
        case .paymentRequired:               return 402
        case .forbidden:                     return 403
        case .notFound:                      return 404
        case .methodNotAllowed:              return 405
        case .notAcceptable:                 return 406


        case .other(let statusCode, _):        return statusCode
        }
    }
}

extension Status {
    public var reasonPhrase: String {
        switch self {
        case .`continue`:                    return "Continue"
        case .switchingProtocols:            return "Switching Protocols"
        case .processing:                    return "Processing"

        case .ok:                            return "OK"
        case .created:                       return "Created"
        case .accepted:                      return "Accepted"
        case .nonAuthoritativeInformation:   return "Non Authoritative Information"
        case .noContent:                     return "No Content"
        case .resetContent:                  return "Reset Content"
        case .partialContent:                return "Partial Content"

        case .multipleChoices:               return "Multiple Choices"
        case .movedPermanently:              return "Moved Permanently"
        case .found:                         return "Found"
        case .seeOther:                      return "See Other"
        case .notModified:                   return "Not Modified"
        case .useProxy:                      return "Use Proxy"
        case .switchProxy:                   return "Switch Proxy"
        case .temporaryRedirect:             return "Temporary Redirect"
        case .permanentRedirect:             return "Permanent Redirect"

        case .badRequest:                    return "Bad Request"
        case .unauthorized:                  return "Unauthorized"
        case .paymentRequired:               return "Payment Required"
        case .forbidden:                     return "Forbidden"
        case .notFound:                      return "Not Found"
        case .methodNotAllowed:              return "Method Not Allowed"
        case .notAcceptable:                 return "Not Acceptable"


        case .other(_, let reasonPhrase):    return reasonPhrase
        }
    }
}

extension Status: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return statusCode
    }
}

public func ==(lhs: Status, rhs: Status) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

The way this is defined I can do a

```
let status = Status (.notFound)
```

and use it with a throw :

```
throw Abort (status)
```

The throw will then show a 404 error with the following text : "Not Found". I want to customize that text. But creating a status :

```
let status = Status(.notFound, reasonPhrase: "my own text")
```

will still show the default text

The only thing I can do is create a status :

```
let status = Status(999, reasonPhrase: "my own text")
```

where the status code is not a standard error number.

This can be confusing and is not standard. Can you show me how in Swift I can override this behavior or extend Status or ... so that I'm able to create a standard error (eg a 404 = .notFound) with a custom text

*** Edit for problems remaining with solution from CRD ***

I added a file with the init extending Status:
extension Status

```
extension Status {
   public init(status: Status, customReason: String)
   {
      self = .other(statusCode: status.statusCode, reasonPhrase: customReason)
   }
}
```

in my code I used it :

```
let status = Status(status: .notFound, customReason: "test")
throw Abort(status)
```

It is still showing: 404 + Not Found on the html page I throw. 
I then added a print, just like CRD did in the playground:

```
let status = Status(status: .notFound, customReason: "test")
print ("\(status.statusCode) : \(status.reasonPhrase)")
throw Abort(status)
```

The print shows : 404: test in the console, the html error page shows 404 + Not Found like it did before. Obviously the abort function from Vapor is manipulating this... grrrr

Comment: Looking at the implementation of the `public init(statusCode: Int, reasonPhrase: String? = nil)` initializer, it is aparrent that it will fall back on the official `reasonPhrase` if it exists, even if a non-`nil` `reasonPhrase` argument is supplied by the caller. If no official `reasonPhrase` exists and none have been supplied by the user, `""` will be used. I'm kind dusty on what the rules are for implementing custom initializers on different files that that of the type declaration (e.g. Vapor's lib), but you could possible implement your own initializer in an `Status` extension.

Comment: that was an idea that came to my mind but I didn't find a way to 'override' the existing init. If I just add an init with the correct code it uses the one from Vapor's lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can add a second `init` in an extension which accepts a `Status` and custom message and returns a `.other`:

```
extension Status
{
   public init(status: Status, customReason: String)
   {
      self = .other(statusCode: status.statusCode, reasonPhrase: customReason)
   }
}
```

which can be used like:

```
let q = Status(status: .notFound, customReason: "This page has ceased to be")
```

**Addendum**

In the Playground:

```
let p = Status(statusCode: Status.notFound.statusCode, reasonPhrase: "This page has ceased to be")
let q = Status(status: .notFound, customReason: "This page has ceased to be")

print("\(p.statusCode) : \(p.reasonPhrase)")
print("\(q.statusCode) : \(q.reasonPhrase)")
```

produces:

```
404 : Not Found
404 : This page has ceased to be
```

HTH

Comment: unfortunately this still produces the standard error message and not the custom message :(

Comment: I copied your code from the question, added the extension, and tested it before posting this answer. I used Xcode 8/Swift 3. As long as you generate a `.other` you will get the custom message regardless of the status value. Check your implementation.

Comment: @Glenn - added Playground output, HTH

Comment: You're right that it works... but it also doesn't work...:(, I'll edit my question to make thing clearer.

Comment: @Glenn - So your original issue has been solved - this question is therefore done. Unfortunately you now have a new problem. You can search the source of Vapour to find out what it is doing and figure a solution. If you get stuck ask a new question, show how far you've got, describe the issue, etc. Somebody will undoubtedly help you.